# Equation Conversion: Polar to Rectangular

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates

Convert the polar equation to rectangular form (rectangular equation)

$$r=\frac{9}{1-3\cos(\theta)}$$

I know that $r^2= x^2+y^2, x= r\cos(\theta)$ and $y= r\sin(\theta)$    and   $\tan(\theta)= y/x$

I don't even understand how to get started.

Comment: do you mean $r=9-3\cos(\theta)$ or $r=\frac{9}{1-3\cos(\theta)}$?

Comment: the second one, it is division, sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $$r=\frac{9}{1-3\cos(\theta)}$$
then we can multiply by $1-3\cos(\theta)$ to get
$$r-3r\cos(\theta)=9$$
now substituting $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $r\cos(\theta)=x$ to get
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-3x=9$$ 
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=9+3x=3(3+x)$$ 
square both sides

$$x^2+y^2=3^2(3+x)^2=9(x^2+6x+9)$$ 
$$y^2=8x^2+54x+81$$ 
thus we gain that 
$$y=\pm \sqrt{8x^2+54x+81}$$

Comment: Thank you! I was getting 8x^2 and 81, but was missing the middle term. My first step was wrong because I wasn't multiplying first. I can see where I went wrong now. I rearranged the answer to equal zero for my homework.